# Parallax website doesn't scroll on mobile (iOS)

Tags: jquery, css, parallax, skrollr

I've found this article about creating parallax website and I've used "Skrollr" plugin for animating pictures on background. But even author's page doesn't work on mobile phones - I can't scroll there. Here is my source: https://ihatetomatoes.net/demos/parallax-scroll-effect/

I've found some script to disable Skrollr when device-width is smaller than 800px, but when I load website on mobile, content doesn't even appear.

Anyone knows how to fix that please??

Thanks!!